# Excel - Sorting based on metric values

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a dataset which looks like:

```
Product Metrics C1  C2  C3
A1          Q1  20  30  10
            Q2  213123  2312    32123
            Q3  454 65  45
            Q4  3   4   6

A2          Q1  10  5   1
            Q2  123 13  23
            Q3  454 65  45
            Q4  3   4   6

A3          Q1  18  6   3
            Q2  123 13  23
            Q3  454 65  45
            Q4  3   4   6
```

Now I want to sort the values based on metric Q1 - From smallest to largest (comparing against the product -A1,A2) then the final dataset should look like,

```
Product Metrics C1      C2     C3
A2      Q1      10       5      1
        Q2     123      13     23
        Q3     454      65     45
        Q4       3       4      6

A3          Q1  18  6   3
            Q2  123 13  23
            Q3  454 65  45
            Q4  3   4   6



A1      Q1      20      30     10
        Q2  213123    2312  32123
        Q3     454      65     45
        Q4       3       4      6
```

hope this gives a clear picture. Thanks in advance guys

Comment: I have tried to re-format your desired output to get a better picture for myself but it seems to me the only difference between the first and the second output is that in the second one you seem to order by `product desc` first and then by `metrics asc`. Is that your intention?

Comment: I have added one more column. Hope it does help for understanding. Sorting is based metric Q1 values. The toughness in this problem is after sorting the format of the dataset should retain back.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would probably do it is transpose your columns and rows so that you have columns for Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4.

Like this:

```
Product Metrics Q1       Q2     Q3     Q4
A1      C1      20   213123    454      3
A1      C2      30     2312     65      4
A1      C3      10    32123     45      6
A2      C1      10      123    454      3
A2      C2       5      13      65     45
A2      C3       1      23      45      6
```

Then you can sort by Q1 using Data>Sort & Filter

Answer (score 0):

CBRF23 already pointed in the right direction but I believe you have to go even a little bit further and flatten each product related sub-array into a single row like

```
A  |  B   C   D |      E     F      G |   H   I   J |  K   L   M
---| Q1 --------|     Q2 ------------ |  Q3 ------- | Q4 -------
Pr | C1  C2  C3 |     C1    C2     C3 |  C1  C2  C3 | C1  C2  C3
A1 | 20  30  10 | 213123  2312  32123 | 454  65  45 |  3   4   6
A2 | 10   5   1 |    123    13     23 | 454  65  45 |  3   4   6
A3 | 18   6   3 |    123    13     23 | 454  65  45 |  3   4   6
```

(The first row just shows the Excel columns, second row the flattened Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4 sections and third row the sub-headers for each column)

Now you can safely sort by column `B`. In case you want to sort by the sum of all Q1 metrics you could introduce another column `N` being the sum of `B,C` and `D` and use that for sorting.

**Update:**

To get your desired output format back there are basically to possibilities:

1. If the number of records is known and fixed you can set-up a "results" page in your excel folder with a list of small "sub-tables". The fields of each sub-array then directly reference the "transposed" fields in a line of the sorted master results array.
2. If the number of results is variable you will have to construct/reconstruct the results page mentioned above using a suitable vba script. The vba generated page can of course also consist of the sorted *values* directly rather than *referencing* the values in the sorted master array.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply! But my problem is like After you done sorting by Transpose the rows-to-column .... How to retain the previous format of data (Look my desired output format)?